# Transforming a bitmap drawable

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm working with a background drawable that I want flipped horizontally (it represents the "back side" of a view). I'd like to do this without making a copy of the original bitmap (memory concerns), and I can't just destroy the original because I'll need it later (when the view is flipped back over).

I tried doing this by extending `BitmapDrawable` and doing some matrix transformations in the `draw(Canvas)` method, but that doesn't work when hardware accelerated.

Here's what I'm doing now as part of my `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()`:

```
BitmapDrawable backgroundDrawable = foo;

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.preScale(-1, 1);

Bitmap flipped = Bitmap.createBitmap(
backgroundDrawable.getBitmap(), 0, 0, backgroundDrawable
    .getBitmap().getWidth(), backgroundDrawable
    .getBitmap().getHeight(), matrix, false);
v.findViewById(R.id.bar).setBackgroundDrawable(
    new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), flipped));
```

It works perfectly except that I now have a duplicate `Bitmap` in memory. Any way around this?

Comment: Also, while the `Bitmap` itself won't be animated, the `View` containing it will, so transformations to the `View` need to be applied to the `Bitmap` as well.